# Deciding how to display DATA for a calendar of events in a UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, database, firebase, cloudkit

I am building an app for iOS for a club at school. I want to store a calendar in the app that will inform users on event information for the club. I am wondering how I should store the data. I want to be able to update the data after I publish the app so we can add or delete events. I was thinking maybe CloudKit or FireBase could be used. I wondering what should I use to hold the data in a way that I can update it in the future? Any suggestions are welcome!

Answer (score 0):

Firebase would be a good start to store the data:
https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/fireapp-dc6ac/database/fireapp-dc6ac/data

**You may want to use Xamarin (Android - Java and iOS - C#) - Microsoft Visual Studio IDE would be a good start.**

I'd suggest to have a look at the following links for more ideas
https://www.syncfusion.com/xamarin-ui-controls/xamarin-calendar
https://github.com/lilcodelab/Xamarin.Plugin.Calendar